# How to play RTSP stream in iOS using mobile vlc kit?

Tags: ios, swift, vlc, rtsp

I am trying to play RTSP url in iOS app using MobileVLCKit , But it's not working.

```
let mediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()
    mediaPlayer.drawable = self.movieView  
    let url = URL(string:"rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov")
    let media = VLCMedia(url: url!)
    mediaPlayer.media = media
    self.mediaPlayer!.play()
```

this given url is working sample url , still i can't play it with shared code.

Comment: Could you share some logs?

Comment: there is no log or error comes , when i run this code , its shows nothing . no video, no error log nothing. atleast  it has to throw some errors so we can do something.

Comment: You need to find logs output so you can know what's going on.

Comment: yes you are right , but unfortunately i am not able to get logs, will you please guide me how to get log from above code .

Comment: likely something this `_mediaplayer.libraryInstance.debugLogging = YES;`

Comment: Hmm, this plays in the Mac version of VLC. We definitely need logs as @mtz suggested.

Comment: if this plays in mac version of vlc then what about mobile version .

Comment: in other sample code for vlc i got this error  "[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x107014000] moov atom not found"

Comment: this works but you dont see anything. Connect a UIView to mediaPlayer.drawable:  mediaPlayer.drawable = toView

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. There is one possibility that the URL you are streaming from does not have HTTPS support so you have to do ATS configuration change to make that happen:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Another problem is make sure you set the delegate of the `VLCMediaPlayer` to your ViewController. I don't know why it does not work without that. You have to set the `delegate` first before setting any other property.

```
    mediaPlayer.delegate = self
    mediaPlayer.drawable = self.videoView
    mediaPlayer.media = VLCMedia(url: URL(string: "https://streams.videolan.org/streams/mp4/Mr_MrsSmith-h264_aac.mp4")!)
    mediaPlayer.play()
```